# yyyymm convert to full sas date (dd/mm/ccyy) - SAS

Tags: date, format, sas

I am trying to get the last day of the month from a field numeric in SAS (`ccyymm`).

for example
201401 would be 31-01-2014.

I have managed to get the field to show as a date type field (still showing as ccyymm though) with the following code in a `PROC SQL` `SELECT statement`

```
year_month_field INFORMAT YYMMN6. AS year_month_date
```

I think that I found some code from another question that had been asked that should give me the last day of the month once I can get the full date.

```
INTNX ( MONTH , year_month_date , 1) -1
```

Will this work? If not any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens? by the way, month needs to be in quotes inside `INTNX` function. ex: `intnx('month', input('201401', yymmn6.), 1)-1`

Comment: I get the following error, I think you may have read and replied before I edited my original question. The field is in fact numeric, and not varchar as I first thought.                            ERROR: INPUT function requires a character argument.
ERROR: Function INTNX requires a numeric expression as argument 2.
ERROR: Expression using subtraction (-) requires numeric types.

Comment: In that case you would first need to use `put` on the numeric yyyymm and then apply input function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the difference between how one would convert a yyyymm to "last day of the month"MMMYYYY format below, depending on whether yyyymm is character or numeric variable.

```
data test;
yyyymm_character='201401';
yyyymm_numeric=201401;

date1=intnx('month', input(yyyymm_character, yymmn6.), 1)-1;
date2=intnx('month', input(put(yyyymm_numeric,6.), yymmn6.), 1)-1;
format date1 date2 date9.;
/*date1=date2=31jan2014*/
run;
```

Alternatively, you can use  the in-built options for `intnx` functions to automatically set any input date to the last day of the respective month. Use `'e'` as shown below.

```
data test;
yyyymm_character='201401';
yyyymm_numeric=201401;

date1=intnx('month', input(yyyymm_character, yymmn6.), 0, 'e');
date2=intnx('month', input(put(yyyymm_numeric,6.), yymmn6.), 0,'e');
format date1 date2 date9.;
/*date1=date2=31jan2014*/
run
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you user102890!