# SAS Num to Date in Quarter format

Tags: date, sas, format

My dataset has a date in NUM format 201011 which is Nov 2010. I want it converted to 2010Q4 in date format. I applied YYQ6. format but it shows results as 2510Q4. What is wrong in here?

```
data abc;
date=201011;
run;

data abc2;
set abc1;
format date YYQ.;
run;
```

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21780410/1056935  In the answer instead of doing format date date9.; you'd do format date yyq6.;

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your date as a date literal, otherwise SAS will interpret it as the number of days since 1st January 1960.

Try this:

```
data abc;
date='01nov2010'd;
run;

data abc2;
set abc1;
format date YYQ.;
run;
```

If you have an existing numeric variable in the format `yyyymm`, you will need to create a new one first before applying the format, e.g.

```
newdate = input(put(date,6.), yymmn6.);
format newdate yyq.;
```

Comment: I cannot change it because the SAS dataset I got has date in the format 201011 format. I have to convert it into Quarter format. The input dataset abc was just an illustration.

Comment: Your input data set has a numeric field in the format nnnnnn (6 digits) which happens to resemble a date, or is it a numeric format with an Official SAS Date format applied to it? Maybe paste in the result of doing a proc contents data=[your data set here]; on it if you are unsure, please?

Comment: Proc contents says NUM  , its a number which resembles a date.

Comment: SAS gives error : The informat YYMM was not found or could not be loaded
when I use newdate = input(date, yymm6.);

Comment: Fixed - it needed `yymmn.` and converting to char first.

Answer (score 0):

```
data _null_;
    datenum=201011;
    dateval=mdy(mod(datenum,100),1,floor(datenum/100));
    put dateval mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Not sure the FLOOR function is necessary--in this case, it worked okay without it.

The question is, is this arithmetic manipulation and use of MDY more or less efficient than converting to character and then back to a date?