# Convert SAS column to Date format

Tags: date, sas

I have a column of dates in the best6. format e.g. 201301 is January 2013, 201402 is February 2014.

Is it possible to convert this to a date9. format?

I would ultimately like to have a column with just the year i.e. 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 etc.

My main table is called "file1" , my column with dates is called "date1" and the column I would like with just the years is called "year1".
I have tried:

```
     data file1;
       year1= date1
       format year1 YEAR4.
     run;
```

But this has not worked. It is giving me an output of two blank cells titled year1 and date1.

Comment: (1) As there is no day of month in 201301, what value would you like to see displayed? (2) Please update the question with what you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yyyymm convert to full sas date (dd/mm/ccyy) - SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779578/yyyymm-convert-to-full-sas-date-dd-mm-ccyy-sas)

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity- I have added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the date1 variable is not a SAS date, i.e., you just have the numeric value 201301 representing January 2013, then you should just be able to use some maths functions, e.g:

```
data want;
   set file1;
   year1 = int(date1/100);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this now!

Comment: This worked for me without the int() and I inserted a format line "format year1 4.; " to round to the nearest while number. Thank you!

Comment: Using the format alone will just display the integer value, but the variable will still hold `2013.01` (inc. decimal places). You can see this by creating `year2` (unformatted) and assign it the value of `year1`. The `int()` function will remove the decimal portion.

Comment: I received an error when I used int() but I will try it again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly awkward as you have to convert from numeric to character and back again:

```
data _null_;
  mydate = 201301;
  mydate9 = input(put(mydate,6.),yymmn6.);
  format mydate9 date9.;
  put _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if it is a 6 digit number and not yymmn6. date format. If it is yymmn6. format you can just add format year4. or date9.. Otherwise agreeing with user667589:

```
data test;
  format date1 year4.;
  set file1;
run;

data test2;
  format mydate9 date9. myyear year4.;
  mydate = 201301;
  mydate9 = input(put(mydate,6.),yymmn6.);
  myyear = mydate9;
run;
```